# Python prevent duplicate text case insensitive

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my GUI program, the data fed to the tree is case insensitive, but Python is case SENSITIVE, and I display the data with first letter Capitalized and keep track of the data with all strings lowercase, and the complicates matters and long story short, this often causes the program to crash.

So I want to prevent case insensitive duplicates from entering the tree.

The tree has three levels and ultimately is populated by a flat list of lists.

If we create an empty tree, and add the following item to it:

`QTreeWidgetItem(['ABC'])`

The above item will be `tree.topLevelItem(0)`

And hereafter this kind of operation is referred to as populate, for example, ['ABC', 'AAA'] populate means create `QTreeWidgetItem(['ABC', 'AAA'])` and add it to `QTreeWidgetItem(['ABC'])`.

I want it like this:

If ['ABC'] has populated the tree, ['abc'] can't populate the tree, ['AAA'] can populate the tree.

If ['ABC', 'AAA'] has populated the tree, ['ABC', 'AAA'] can't populate the tree, ['ABC', 'aaa'] can't populate the tree, ['ABC', 'ABA'] can populate the tree, however ['abc', 'ABA'] can populate the tree as ['ABC', 'ABA'] if ['ABC', 'ABA'] hasn't populated the tree.

If ['ABC', 'AAA', 'AAA'] has populated the tree, ['abc', 'aaa', 'aaa'] can't populate the
tree, however ['abc', 'aaa', 'bbb'] can populate the tree as ['ABC', 'AAA', 'bbb'] if it hasn't populated yet.

In short, given a list of strings with length between 1 to 3, add its last string to a nested dictionary, the lowercases of values in its destination shouldn't contain its lowercase, and the destination is determined by the first n elements in the list, each a key at the depth of their index of the nested dictionary, and a value of the previous key (if exist), and the destination is the nested indexes where the lowercases of indexes equal to the lowercases of the first n elements, else create the nested keys.

I treefied the flat data with something like this:

```py
entries = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for i in data:
    entries[i[0]][i[1]].append(i[2])
```

And I want `entries` to automatically correct the keys if the lowercases of the keys (the last one if the value) are already present in `entries` (i = ['ABC', 'bbb', 'CCC'], add 'CCC' to entries['abc']['BBB'] if the keys exist else add 'CCC' to entries['ABC']['bbb']) to prevent case insensitive duplicates.

Here is a minimal working example of what I intend to do, minus the recursion part and nesting part, it only deals with strings:

```py
class Caseless:
    def __init__(self):
        self.strings = list()
    def reply(self, string):
        same = next((i for i in self.strings if i.lower() == string.lower()), None)
        if same:
            return same
        self.strings.append(string)
        return string
    def toList(self):
        return self.strings

In [1]: class Caseless:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.strings = list()
   ...:     def reply(self, string):
   ...:         same = next((i for i in self.strings if i.lower() == string.lower()), None)
   ...:         if same:
   ...:             return same
   ...:         self.strings.append(string)
   ...:         return string
   ...:     def toList(self):
   ...:         return self.strings

In [2]: c = Caseless()

In [3]: c.toList()
Out[3]: []

In [4]: c.reply('AAA')
Out[4]: 'AAA'

In [5]: c.reply('aaa')
Out[5]: 'AAA'

In [6]: c.toList()
Out[6]: ['AAA']

In [7]: c.reply('abc')
Out[7]: 'abc'

In [8]: c.reply('ABC')
Out[8]: 'abc'

In [9]: c.toList()
Out[9]: ['AAA', 'abc']
```

I want to know what is a better way to achieve the same result, and how to make it have a recursion feature?

---

So this is the code I come up with that gets the job done:

```py
class CaselessDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def add(self, k):
        same = next((i for i in self.keys() if i.lower() == k[0].lower()), None)
        if not same:
            same = k[0]
            self.update({k[0]: dict()})
        if len(k) >= 2:
            rsame = next((i for i in self[same].keys() if i.lower() == k[1].lower()), None)
            if not rsame:
                rsame = k[1]
                self[same].update({k[1]: list()})
        if len(k) == 3:
            rrsame = next((i for i in self[same][rsame] if i.lower() == k[2].lower()), None)
            if not rrsame:
                self[same][rsame].append(k[2])
```

I am able to do recursion but I need the third level to be a list and the class must have only up to three levels.

Can any one offer a better solution?